# Frailty model using bootstrap sampling

Tags: r, frailty

Let say I have a 'kidney catheter' data set which is built in `survival` package. Data are about the recurrence times to infection, at the point of insertion of the catheter, for kidney patients using portable dialysis equipment. Catheters may be removed for reasons other than infection, in which case the observation is censored. Each patient has exactly 2 observations.

**We can use shared frailty model to model this correlated survival times. The unobserved risk factor that is common for all the observations in the same individual or cluster is called the frailty. By performing the bootstrap, we obtain for each simulated data set a bootstrap estimate of the heterogeneity or frailty parameter. How can we estimate the frailty parameter with model based bootstrap approach using `R code`?**

Comment: Do you mean the SHARE frailty model? I think you will need to provide more clarification to allow people to help with answering your question.

Comment: Yes, BGreene, I mean shared frailty model. Basically I am following this technical report: http://sites.uclouvain.be/IAP-Stat-Phase-V-VI/PhaseV/publications_2003/TR/TR0348.pdf